# Arguments of Column in SqlAlchemy Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm looking for docs of the `Column` definition, I want to know how many args the function `Column` has.

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html#simple-example

http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.0/api/#sessions

Sample Code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    pw_hash = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

And I have found nothing.

Comment: Check the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column).

Comment: I love you, it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From SQLAlchemy documentation:

```
sqlalchemy.schema.Column(name, type, *args, **kwargs)
```

Where `name`is a `str` and `type` is an instance subclassing `TypeEngine`.

More information about `**kwargs` in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column).

Comment: The "documentation" link appears to be broken as of Jan 2019.  Correct link: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column